# Delaying text change until animation completes in android

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, textview

I want this `animation` to be complete before the new text appears. Currently, the new text appears before the `animation` begins. Any ideas on how to `delay` the text change?

This is the `animation xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

And here is my code:

```
fun slideLeft(){questionText.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_out_left)) questionText.text = "New Text coming here"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried working around `AnimationListener` ?

```
 textView.animation.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
                  // do something before animation
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
                 // do something after animation
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {
            }
     })
```